# Why is Elektron not considered being as 'RESTful' as compared to angular?

Tags: angular, rest, frontend

I'm taking considerations in using particular frameworks when designing a niche multiplayer based card game that will be available over the internet, and I'm trying to understand why the Elektron framework is not considered 'RESTful' or as 'RESTful' as angular for a front-end that makes requests to a server

From the sources I've reviewed, both have the capabilities of getting the job done, how does one quantify something being RESTful, or more RESTful than something else that can accomplish the same task in a different way?

Comment: Angular is not restful, it can communicate with a restful service for data but Angular is not restful.

Comment: Elektron and Angular are not opposing systems, they are complimentary. Neither are or aren't RESTful because the 'REST' part is typically on the server. While I think it's possible for a frontend to be have a true RESTful client, neither really do by most definitions.

Comment: Perhaps it was a site trying to project things in a indeterminable way. https://stackshare.io/stackups/angularjs-vs-electron